# Unexplained pry behavior in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pry, binding.pry

The bug on line `11` is put there on purpose. I am curious about how `pry` works in this example.

In the code below, when I enter `pry`, if I type `name` I get `nil`, which means that `pry` is outputting the value of the local variable which will be initialized on line `11`. However, there is a getter method `name` and if I output its value on line `9` I get "Nemo".

Does `pry` first looks for local variables in a method? If so, how come that `name` is not undefined on line `9`?

```rb
class Animal               
  attr_accessor :name      
                            
  def initialize(name)      
    @name = name            
  end                       
                            
  def change_name    
    binding.pry  
    p name   
    name = name.upcase      
  end                       
end                         
                            
fish = Animal.new('Nemo')     
p fish.name # => 'Nemo'       
p fish.change_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name =` is a variable assignment, which means `name` is a local variable.

Ruby anticipates this and interprets all instances of `name` in that method to be as such. It seems like psychic knowledge, but remember Ruby has already read and compiled this function long before it is actually executed.

Comment: Thank you. What I am not sure is why `pry` doesn't see getter `name` method instead of the local variable since when we output `name` on line `9` it outputs `Nemo` correctly?

Comment: Ruby variables and implicit method calls are, syntax-wise, identical. If you want to force the method, use `self.name` to be explicit.